# Using ngIf in Ionic html file to display different cards based on the URL

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I started my Ionic project off of the ionic sidemenu template. With this template, a hamburger menu appears, and clicking the different options changes the endpoints/URL on a local server. I'm trying to change what is displayed on the screen based on the current URL, but it seems like if I continue switching URL's, the old content never disappears, and it will continuously display more and more content. I was wondering if there was a way to hide/remove this content unless you were on that screen, or if there was a way to register the click events from a hamburger menu to avoid using the URL entirely.

```html
<ion-card-title id="collegeCardHome" *ngIf="docURL == 'http://localhost:8100/folder/Home' ">
  {{collegeInfoArray2[0].name}}
</ion-card-title>
<ion-card-title id="collegeCardLikes" *ngIf="docURL == 'http://localhost:8100/folder/Favorites'">
  {{likedCollegesArray[0].name}}
</ion-card-title>
<ion-card-title id="collegeCardDislikes"*ngIf="docURL == 'http://localhost:8100/folder/Dislikes'">
  {{dislikedCollegesArray[0].name}}
</ion-card-title>
```

Thank you!

edit - code for getting URL is below inside of my .ts file!

```js
public docURL = document.URL;
```

edit 2 - added code from my TS file

```js
export class FolderPage implements OnChanges, OnInit {

  public folder: string;
  
  public collegeInfoArray2 = [
    {
      name : 'Name1',
      size : 'Size1'
    },
    {
      name : 'Name2',
      size : 'Size2' 
    },
    {
      name : 'Name3',
      size : 'Size3'
    }
  ]
  public sizeOfCollegeInfoArray = this.collegeInfoArray2.length;

  public likedCollegesArray = [];
  public dislikedCollegesArray = [];

  public link:HTMLElement = document.getElementById("testingHome");

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }
  public docURL;

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.docURL  = document.URL;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.folder = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    //this.link.className = "showItem";
  }

  likeFirst() {
    if (this.sizeOfCollegeInfoArray > 0) {
      this.likedCollegesArray.push(this.collegeInfoArray2[0]);
      this.collegeInfoArray2.splice(0,1);
      console.log(this.likedCollegesArray[0].name);
      this.sizeOfCollegeInfoArray--;
    }
  }

  dislikeFirst() {
    if (this.sizeOfCollegeInfoArray > 0) {
      this.dislikedCollegesArray.push(this.collegeInfoArray2[0]);
      this.collegeInfoArray2.splice(0,1);
      console.log(this.dislikedCollegesArray[0].name);
      console.log(this.dislikedCollegesArray[0].size);
      this.sizeOfCollegeInfoArray--;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: can you share the code for assigning docURL value?

Comment: @Eytan just added it, thanks!

Comment: Do you call it on ngAfterContentInit() or a similar hook?

Comment: @Eytan I just call it inside of my export class, which implements OnInit, so i dont believe I have any hooks like that!

Comment: Ok, so first of all I'd recommend going over the angular [lifecycles](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), you can just import and implement it in you component

Comment: i would also use === rather than ==. And there is typo in your last block as there is no space between id="collegeCardDislikes"*ngIf 

Also if you could post more completely the code it would be useful in giving more precise assistance.

Comment: @Eytan thanks for the advice - I tried that with ngOnChanges and put my calls in there, but now my ionic cards don't have the info from the arrays.

Comment: @E.Maggini I'll be sure to use ===, and I just added the code from my TS file!

Comment: this is still sufficient code. What is intended to trigger the onChange? What is in the sie menu?

Comment: @E.Maggini the onChange is intended to be triggered based off of the URL changing, which occurs from clicking the buttons on the side menu. The side menu is just built off of the standard ionic template; ionic start sidemenu.

Comment: @CS442 that's probably because of similar reasons, I'm not sure about your logic but it seems like you need to populate the liked\dislikedCollegesArray before you render the view.